# Why did we stop creating functions at exponents?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, exponentiation, puzzle, philosophy, multiplicative-function

It seems that every new function is just a function that asks something of the one before it, for example: First we have addition. That is the starting point. Now, multiplication, which asks "How many times to we add this number to itself." Then we went to exponents, which asks "How many times do we multiply this number to itself."

Why did we not create something that asks "how many times do we exponentiate this number to itself?"

Seems like the next step to me. We could even keep going forever and ever. How do we represent this in mathematics?

Comment: This is known as tetration - see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration

Comment: There are extensions to exponentiation : tetration , pentation and so on (generalized with Knuth's uparrow notation) , but they are hard to manipulate. For example, comparing the size of two expressions is far from easy. The numbers are usually so big , that calculators cannot just compute them. Above tetration, there is no known purpose of such expressions than just constructing extremely large numbers.

Comment: The only places where I have seen nested exponentiation is in contrived math contest problems. There might be some applications of which I am unaware, but I can only imagine how little even higher iterations come up in practice.

Comment: Note that we already lose the associativity in the case of exponentiation , we usually have $a^{(b^c)}\ne (a^b)^c$ , the latter is $a^{b\cdot c}$ hence $a^{(b^c)}$ typically is much larger.

Comment: @Loobear23 Please post as answer so I checkmark it.

Comment: Instead of addition, I would say that the successor function is the starting point. Multiplication is repeated addition, but addition is repeated succession. See Peano axioms.